# Python Automated Data Driven Pages - Labeling and Symbolizing Errors

Tags: arcpy, data-driven-pages

I am trying to use a python script to automate the export of the data driven map document.

However when I use the python script to run the DDP export some of the labels are not exported and the symbols that have a rotation angle based on a attribute in the layer table is not rotating.

Other than the labels and the symbols the python script to automate the exports works fine.

When I run the DDP manually (through the MXD) all the labels and symbols are exported correctly.  Have anyone else encountered this problem?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include a code snippet that demonstrates what you are describing, please?  A picture of the same extent both in ArcMap and when exported (to PDF?) would also be useful.

Comment: I experienced very similar thing by just printing to pdf - labels were missing on most of the pages, but 1st. Ended up exporting map.